# Vuetify When I click select box, it will clean up my object value?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

There is a form to create a record, when I click v-select it will clean up my "projectManagers" Obj [name, email, phone_numer]

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="projectManagers.name"
    label="Name"
    dense
    outlined
    :rules="[rules.required]"
></v-text-field>
<v-text-field
    v-model="projectManagers.email"
    label="Email"
    dense
    outlined
    :rules="[rules.required]"
></v-text-field>
<v-text-field
    v-model="projectManagers.phone_number"
    label="Phone Number"
    dense
    outlined
    :rules="[rules.required]"
></v-text-field>
<v-select
    :items="statusList"
    v-model="status"
    label="Status"
    dense
    outlined
></v-select>
```

Comment: Can you reproduce it on CodeSandbox ?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to clear the values after selecting an item of your `v-select`, you can do it like so:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  watch: {
    status(newVal) {
      if (newVal) {
        this.projectManagers.name = "";
        this.projectManagers.email = "";
        this.projectManagers.phone_number = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanna keep the record after Tigger select box. There is a problem after I click the select box, it will automatically clear the values.